# How to use regex and grep on GNU version?

Tags: unix, grep

I have text file with following content:

```
Bought line for campaign : 8326197571 on provider TEST
Bought line for campaign : 3326147521 on provider TEST
```

Want get from this file using `grep` only phone number so tried use:

```
grep -oh '\d\{10\}' test.txt
```

On my my it works perfectly on server returns nothing. But if i just try:

```
grep '\d*' test.txt
```

it return all string with numbers.

Server grep version

```
grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
```

Mac versions

```
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
```

Seems like issue in difference GNU and BSD but how to do it works on GNU?

Comment: The answer is to be found in `man grep`, where the regex syntax is described in sufficient detail.

Comment: @MadPhysicisty yep i read it but i do not see answer on my question

Comment: You are right. I found my main answer by doing `man sed` of all strange things :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use `[[:digit:]]` instead of `\d` to represent the character class:

```
$ grep -oh '[[:digit:]]\{10\}' <<< 'Bought line for campaign : 8326197571 on provider TEST
Bought line for campaign : 3326147521 on provider TEST'
8326197571
3326147521
```

Alternatively, you can enable Perl-style regexes with `-P` to preserve the original expression (but without escaping the braces):

```
grep -ohP '\d{10}'
```

Comment: Gotta collect all me lucky sharms

Comment: Added another option.